# fetch data from mysql db with js or java, no php usage

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, google-tag-manager

which is the best approach to open connection to a db that is on another domain with js, java.

Example, im using gtm to push data to a datalyer, all i have is front-end access, but i have access to the data base on another domain, how can i fetch the data from the other data base to gtm when gtm only allows js no php coding, so the date can be dynamic since the data that i need to push is coming from the external database.

Thanks in advance

```
<script>

var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
 document.write(rs.fields(1));
  rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;

    dataLayer.push({
  'usersigendup': 'some-value',
    'productID2': 'some-value2',
    'productID3': 'some-value3',
 });

 </script>
```

The above code isnt working, but basically how can i accomplish that "some-value" become the result of a value fecthed from the DB.that is what i found so far googling

Comment: If you're trying to run this code in a browser (the `<script>` tags), then this definitely isn't going to work. Despite the fact it's JavaScript, you can't run NodeJS code within the browser.

Comment: I used node.js code as an example and my bad for not explaining that, in php i can get this done, but with js i will like the best approach since is the only option i have

Comment: If you don't have server access, you can't setup a direct database connection using JavaScript. You could potentially make a CORS request to another server (which in turn connects to the database and returns your data), but that gets into a whole other set of possibilities.

Comment: i have acces to the database tables and credentials i need to fetch one table and the data put it into a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTM has no serverside API for tracking, so you cannot send data directly (also you do not want to give database credentials to a client-side script).

You could create a serverside script that fetches data from your database.  Then you make this available via an URL that returns the database result. Then you create a custom HTML tag with a JavaScript that connects to your new endpoint, fetches the response and parses it into variables that you then use in your tracking tags.

You would need to make sure that your script still works (or terminates properly) when there is no response from your endpoint.

Simo Ahava [demonstrated the technique in an older article](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/send-weather-data-to-google-analytics-in-gtm-v2/) of his, the only difference is that instead of using an availaibe webservice like the weather API you would have to create your own service that returns your database results.